# Globbing patterns in windows command prompt/ powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, command-prompt, glob

I would like to know if there is any way to achieve this behavior on windows, for example:

***/b?n/ca? /etc/pa??wd*** -> executes 'cat /etc/passwd'

Comment: The path globbing behavior is possible, (but the exact command is not since there's no `/bin/cat` executable in Windows). Simply use the `&` invocation operator and `Get-Command` (alias `gcm`): `& (gcm 'Get-C?nte?t') .\spycloud.py`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for your reply, it works !! Is it possible to do that also in the classic command prompt?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell you can use [Resolve-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) which *Resolves the wildcard characters in a path, and displays the path contents.*

Example: I want to locate signtool.exe from the Windows SDK which typically resides in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" where there could be any other version(s) installed.

So I could use: `Resolve-Path 'c:\program*\Windows Kits\10\bin\*\x64\signtool.exe'`

EDIT:

If you want to execute it directly you can use the `&` invocation operator e.g.

`&(Resolve-Path 'c:\wind?ws\n?tepad.exe')`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate! how would you combine that path resolution with @mathies's comment?  I mean: it just resolves the wildcards as you say, but does not execute the program called. And do you know if that is possible even without powershell?

Comment: See edit @jagghy and afaik not possible in the cmd prompt

Comment: One last tip: how would you pass a complex command using this behavior, for example: more c:\windows\win.ini | findstr "fonts"

Comment: `Resolve-Path 'c:\w?ndows\win.ini' | gc | select-string 'fonts'`

Comment: In general `Resolve-Path` is a good tool to resolve wildcard paths. For the case of executing a program you don't need it though: `& 'c:\wind?ws\n?tepad.exe'` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I really appreciate your help! @Remko saldy your suggestion does not work. I tried this: & 'c:\wind?ws\System32\more.com' C:\Users\...\Desktop\something.txt | findstr "something" and it works. But how do I apply the same concept also to the arguments given?

Comment: I think you’re struggling with mixing  cmd and powershell. If using the latter, easier to use native cmdlets such as Get-Content rather than more and select-string rather than findstr

Answer (score 8):

- **With limited exceptions in PowerShell, on Windows there is *no* support for *shell-level* globbing - *target commands themselves* must perform resolution of wildcard patterns** to matching filenames; if they don't, globbing must be performed *manually, up front*, and the results passed as literal paths; see the bottom section for background information.
- **PowerShell**:

  - Perhaps surprisingly, you *can* invoke an *executable* by wildcard pattern, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, though *that behavior is problematic* (see bottom section):

    ```bash
    # Surprisingly DOES find C:\Windows\System32\attrib.exe
    # and invokes it.
    C:\Windows\System3?\attr*.exe /?
    ```

    - Generally, you can discover commands, including external programs, via the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Command) cmdlet.
  - **Many file-processing cmdlets in PowerShell *do* perform their own globbing (e.g., `Get-ChildItem`, `Remove-Item`); if you're calling commands that do not, notably external programs that don't, you must perform globbing *manually*, up front**, except on *Unix*-like platforms when calling *external programs*, where PowerShell *does* perform automatic globbing (see bottom section):

    - Use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Convert-Path) to get the full, file-system-native paths of matching files or directories.

      - While [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Resolve-Path) may work too, it returns *objects* whose `.ProviderPath` property you need to access to get the same information (*stringifying* these objects, as happens implicitly when you pass them to external programs, yields their `.Path` property, which may be based on *PowerShell-only* drives that external programs and .NET APIs know nothing about.)
    - For more control over what is matched, use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) and access the result objects' `.Name` or `.FullName` property, as needed; for instance, `Get-ChildItem` allows you to limit matching to *files* (`-File`) or *directories* (`-Directory`) only.
    - **PowerShell makes it easy to use the results of manually performed globbing *programmatically***; the following example passes the full paths of all `*.txt` files in the current directory to the `cmd.exe`'s `echo` command as individual arguments; PowerShell automatically encloses paths with spaces in `"..."`, if needed:

      ```bash
       cmd /c echo (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt).FullName
      ```
    - Generally, note that PowerShell's [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) are more powerful than those of the host platform's file-system APIs, and notably include support for character sets (e.g. `[ab]`) and ranges (e.g. `[0-9]`); another important difference is that `?` matches *exactly one* character, whereas the native file-system APIs - both on Windows and Unix-like platforms - match *none or one*.

      - However, when using the `-Filter` parameter of file-processing cmdlets such as `Get-ChildItem`, it is the host platform's file-system APIs that are used, which - while limiting features (as noted) - *improves performance*.
- **`cmd.exe` (Command Prompt, the legacy shell)**:

  - `cmd.exe` does *not* support calling *executables* by wildcard pattern;  ***some* of `cmd.exe`'s internal commands (e.g., `dir` and `del`) and *some* standard external programs (e.g., `attrib.exe`) *do* perform their own globbing; otherwise you must perform globbing *manually*, up front**:

    - `where.exe`, the external program for discovering external programs fundamentally only supports wildcard patterns in executable *names* (e.g. `where find*.exe`), not in *paths*, which limits wildcard-based lookups to executables located in directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

      ```bash
      :: OK - "*" is part of a *name* only
      where.exe find*.exe

      :: !! FAILS: "*" or "?" must not be part of a *path*
      :: !! -> "ERROR: Invalid pattern is specified in "path:pattern"."
      where.exe C:\Windows\System32\find*.exe
      ```
    - Globbing via `dir` appears to be limited to wildcard characters in the *last* path component:

      ```bash
      :: OK - "*" is only in the *last* path component.
      dir C:\Windows\System32\attri*

      :: !! FAILS: "*" or "?" must not occur in *non-terminal* components.
      :: !! -> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
      dir C:\Windows\System3?\attri*
      ```
    - **Using manual globbing results *programmatically* is quite *cumbersome* in `cmd.exe`** and requires use of `for` statements (whose wildcard matching has the same limitations as the `dir` command); for example, using the syntax for *batch files* (`.cmd` or `.bat` files):

      - To use the resolved executable file path for invocation (assuming only *one* file matches):

        ```bash
        @echo off
        setlocal

        :: Use a `for` loop over a wildcard pattern to enumerate
        :: the matching filenames - assumed to be just *one* in this case,
        :: namely attrib.exe, and save it in a variable.
        for %%f in (C:\Windows\System32\attr*.exe) do set "Exe=%%f"

        :: Execute the resolved filename to show its command-line help.
        "%Exe%" /?
        ```
      - To pass matching filenames as multiple arguments to a single command:

        ```bash
        @echo off
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

        :: Use a `for` loop over a wildcard pattern to enumerate
        :: matching filenames and collect them in a single variable.
        set files=
        for %%f in (*.txt) do set files=!files! "%%f"

        :: Pass all matching filenames to `echo` in this example.
        echo %files%
        ```

---

##### Background information:

- **On *Unix*-like platforms, POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash *themselves* perform *globbing* (resolving filename wildcard patterns to matching filenames), *before* the target command sees the resulting filenames**, as part of a feature set called [*shell expansions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) (link is to the Bash manual).
- **On *Windows*, `cmd.exe`** (the legacy shell also known as Command Prompt) **does NOT perform such expansions and PowerShell *mostly* does NOT**.

  - That is, **it is generally *up to each target command* to interpret wildcard patterns as such** and resolve them to matching filenames.

    - That said, in PowerShell, many built-in commands, known as *cmdlets*, *do* support PowerShell's [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards), notably via the `-Path` parameter of [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers) cmdlets, such as [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem).
    - Additionally and more generally, cmdlet parameters that represent *names* often support wildcards too; e.g., `Get-Process exp*` lists all processes whose image name start with `exp`, such as `explorer`.
    - Note that the absence of Unix-style shell expansions on Windows also implies that *no* semantic distinction is made between *unquoted* and *quoted* arguments (e.g., `*.txt` vs. `"*.txt"`): a target command generally sees *both* as *verbatim* `*.txt`.
  - In **PowerShell**, **automatic globbing DOES occur** in these **limited cases**:

    - Perhaps surprisingly, **an *executable* file path *can* be invoked via a wildcard pattern**:

      - as-is, if the pattern isn't enclosed in `'...'` or `"..."` and/or contains no variable references or expressions; e.g.:

        ```bash
         C:\Windows\System3?\attri?.exe
        ```
      - via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), otherwise; e.g.:

        ```bash
         & $env:SystemRoot\System32\attri?.exe
        ```
      - However, **this feature is of questionable utility** - When would you *not* want to know up front what *specific* executable you're invoking? - and it is unclear whether it was implemented *by design*, given that inappropriate wildcard processing surfaces in other contexts too - see [GitHub issue #4726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4726).

        - Additionally, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.4, if *two or more* executables match the wildcard pattern, a misleading error occurs, suggesting that *no* matching executable was found - see [GitHub issue #17468](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17468); a variation of the problem also affects passing a wildcard-based *path* (as opposed to a mere *name*) that matches multiple executables to [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Command).
        - In POSIX-compatible shells, the multi-match scenario is handled differently, but is equally useless: the *first* matching executable is invoked, and all others are passed *as its arguments*.
    - **On *Unix*-like platforms only, PowerShell *emulates* the globbing feature of POSIX-compatible shells *when calling external programs***, in an effort to behave more like the platform-native shells; if PowerShell didn't do that, something as simple as `ls *.txt` would fail, given that the external `/bin/ls` utility would then receive *verbatim* `*.txt` as its argument.

      - However, this **emulation has limitations**, as of PowerShell 7.2.4:

        - The inability to use wildcard patterns that contain *spaces* - see [GitHub issue #10683](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10683), and, conversely, the inability to individually `` ` ``-escape wildcard metacharacters in order to suppress globbing - see [GitHub issue #18038](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18038)
        - The inability to include *hidden* files - see [GitHub issue #4683](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4683).