# How to list contents of a specific directory in powershell?

Tags: powershell, path, escaping, string-literals, backslash

I'm rather baffled by Powershell in general. Very weird. Anyway, I've read:

[Powershell's equivalent to Linux's: ls -al](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66269685/1593077)

so I now know how to list the contents of the current directory. But how can I list the contents of an arbitrary directory?

Specifically,

- How do I type in the path I want to check?

  - in Windows, `\` is the directory separator; but it's also an escape char in most languages. What do I do with it?
  - Do I need single-quotes? Double-quotes? No-quotes?
- Where do I place the argument relative to the switches? After, like I'm used to, or rather before?
- If I want to use an environment variable, or a powershell variable, as part of the path to list - how do I do that?

Comment: I realized I missed some of your questions originally. I've restructured the answer into two sections: Section one contains general information about `Get-ChildItem`, how parameter syntax is described in PowerShell's help system, and how examples can be printed. Section two answers your specific questions in a manner that may help readers coming from POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash.

Answer (score 2):

**General PowerShell information and examples:**

PowerShell-native commands, including user-authored ones that opt in, have standardized parameter syntax and binding rules, so the following, focused on `Get-ChildItem`, applies generally:

- See the [help topic for `Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), which describes the command's purpose, syntax, and individual parameters, along with showing examples.

  - If you have offline help installed (true by default in *Windows PowerShell*; installable on demand via [`Update-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help) in PowerShell (Core) 7+), you can also **print the examples with `Get-Help -Example Get-ChildItem | more`**
- As for how to generally read the notation describing the supported parameters listed under the `SYNTAX` heading of cmdlet help topics, which PowerShell calls *syntax diagrams*, see the conceptual [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) help topic.
- Offline, you can print the syntax diagrams for PowerShell-native commands with standard switch `-?` or by passing the command name to `Get-Command -Syntax` (`Get-ChildItem -?` or `Get-Command -Syntax Get-ChildItem`). To also access the help *text* offline, you may have to install local help first, as described above.

**Examples**:

```bash
# The following commands all pass "\" (the [current drive's] root dir)
# to the -Path parameter.
# Note: 
#  * "\" is NOT special in PowerShell, so it needs no escaping.
#    PowerShell allows use of "/" instead even on Windows.
#  * -Path arguments are interpreted as wildcard patterns, whether
#     quoted or not. You may pass *multiple* paths / patterns.
#  * Switch -Force - which, as all switches - can be placed anywhere
#    among the arguments, requests that *hidden* items be listed too.

Get-ChildItem -Path \ -Force
Get-ChildItem \ -Force  # ditto, with *positional* param. binding
'\' | Get-ChildItem     # ditto, via the pipeline.
Get-ChildItem / -Force  # ditto, with "/" as alternative to "\"

# To force interpretation as a *literal* path - which matters for
# paths that contain "[" chars. - use -LiteralPath.
# Here too you may pass *multiple* paths.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath \ -Force

# Quoting is needed for paths with spaces, for instance.

# Single-quoting treats the string *verbatim*:
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\dir with spaces'

# Double-quoting *expands* (interpolates) variable references
# and subexpressions.
Get-ChildItem "$HOME\dir with spaces"

# A variable alone can be used as-is, without double-quoting, even
# if its value contains spaces.
Get-ChildItem $HOME
```

---

To answer **your specific questions**, for **readers who come from POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash**:

> How do I type in the path I want to check?

[`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) offers two ways to specify one or more input paths, as most file-processing cmdlets in PowerShell do:

- `-Path` accepts one or more names or paths that are interpreted as a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) pattern.

  - Note that - unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash - it does *not* matter whether the path is unquoted or not; e.g., `Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt`, `Get-ChildItem "*.txt"`, and `Get-ChildItem '*.txt'` are all equivalent; more on that below (note the incidental omission of `-Path` in the latter two calls, which makes `"*.txt"` and `'*.txt'` bind *positionally* to the first positional parameter, `-Path`).
- `-LiteralPath` accepts one or more names or paths that are assumed to refer to existing file-system items *literally* (verbatim).

  - Given that literal paths on Unix-like platforms usually do *not* contain `*` and `?` characters and on Windows *cannot*, use of `-LiteralPath` for disambiguation is usually only necessary for paths that contain `[` (and possibly also `]`), given that [PowerShell's wildcard pattern language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) also supports character sets and ranges (e.g. `[ab]` and `[0-9]`).
  - Binding to `-LiteralPath` via an *argument* requires explicit use of `-LiteralPath`, i.e. use of a *named* argument; e.g., `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath foo`
  - However, supplying `System.IO.FileInfo` and/or `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` instances (such as output by (another) `Get-ChildItem` or [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) call) *via the pipeline* DOES bind to `-LiteralPath`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375).

> in Windows, `\` is the directory separator; but it's also an escape char in most languages. What do I do with it?

In PowerShell `\` is *not* an escape character, so `\` instances are treated as literals and do *not* require escaping; it is `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick* that serves as the escape character in PowerShell - see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.

Note, however, that PowerShell generally allows you to use `\` and `/` in paths *interchangeably*, so that, e.g., `Get-ChildItem C:/Windows` works just fine.

> Where do I place the argument relative to the switches? After, like I'm used to, or rather before?

Note:

- ***All* parameters have *names* in PowerShell** - that is, there is *no* POSIX-like distinction between *options* (e.g. `-l` and *operands* (value-only arguments, such as the `/` in `ls -l /`).
- A command *may* declare parameters that may also be passed by *value only*, positionally, meaning that prefixing the value with the parameter name is then *optional* (e.g., `Get-Path /` as shorthand for `Get-Path -Path /`).

Only parameters that *require a value (argument)* can *potentially* be passed as *values only* - depending on the parameter declaration of the target command - in which case their *order matters*:

- *Value-only* arguments are called *positional* arguments, and they bind *in order* to those parameters of the target command that are *declared* as positional, if any - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375) for how to discover which of a given command's parameters are positional ones.
- Prefixing a value by its target parameter (e.g., `-LiteralPath /some/path`) makes it a *named* argument.

A *switch* (flag) in PowerShell, such as `-Force`, is a special parameter type - Boolean in nature - that by definition requires passing it as a *named* argument, typically *without a value* (though you *can* attach a value, e.g. `-Force:$true` or `-Force:$false` - note that `:` is then required to separate the parameter name from its value; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250136/45375) for details).

- As an aside: Unlike POSIX-compliant utilities, PowerShell does *not* support parameters with *optional values* of any other type - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848736/45375).

Since PowerShell allows *named* arguments to be specified in *any* order, the implication is that you're free to place by-definition-named switch arguments such as `-Force` anywhere on the command line.

In short: **Order only matters among *positional* (unnamed) arguments** in PowerShell.

See the conceptual [about_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameters) help topic for more information.

> Do I need single-quotes? Double-quotes? No-quotes?

A path (parameter value in general) needs quoting:

- if it contains PowerShell metacharacters, notably *spaces*; e.g. `C:\path\to\foo` needs no quoting, whereas `C:\path with spaces\to\foo` does.
- if it starts with a [subexpression (`$(...)`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), in which case you need *double*-quoting, i.e. `"..."` (see below) - though you may choose to *always* use `"..."`-quoting for paths involving subexpressions or variable references.
- Note that **PowerShell has *no* concept that is the equivalent of the so-called shell expansions in POSIX-compatible shells** such as Bash; therefore, whether a given argument is quoted or not makes *no semantic difference* (assuming it doesn't *require* quoting); as noted above, `*.txt`, `'*.txt'` and `"*.txt"` are all equivalent, and it is the *target command*, not PowerShell itself, that interprets the pattern - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72468013/45375) for more information.

If quoting is needed:

- [Verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) treat their content *verbatim*
- [Expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) perform *string interpolation* ("expand" embedded variables and subexpressions, i.e replace them with their values).

> If I want to use an environment variable, or a powershell variable, as part of the path to list - how do I do that?

To use such variables as-is, no quoting is needed (even if the values contain spaces):

```bash
# PowerShell variable:
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $HOME

# Environment variable, e.g. on Windows:
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:USERPROFILE
```

To make a variable (or expression) part of a larger string, embed it in an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings); e.g.:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$HOME/Desktop"
```

Note:

- Embedding the output from *expressions* or *commands* requires use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--); e.g. 
  `Get-ChildItem "$(Get-Variable -ValueOnly Home)/Desktop"`; for a complete overview of PowerShell's expandable strings (string interpolation), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).
- Situationally, such as in the example above, *omitting* the `"..."` quoting would work too - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) for more information.

Additionally and alternatively, PowerShell allows you to use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) to pass the result of arbitrary expressions and commands as arguments; the following is the equivalent of the command above:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath ($HOME + '/Desktop')
```

Alternatively, using the [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Join-Path $HOME Desktop)
```

Comment: +1 for effort, but I have to admit - the length of (the second part of ) your answer is somewhat of a demotivator :-(

Comment: @einpoklum, yes, it's long, but comprehensive - and necessary, if you want to invest the time to learn PowerShell properly. Not everyone does, and my hope is that the annotated examples in the first section are enough for those that don't. Regardless of what category you fall into, let me know if either section is missing something.